# SQL Server 2005: Copy database failing with unhelpful error

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-event-log, ssis, copying

```
>   Event Name: OnTaskFailed  Message:  
> Operator: ***\administrator 
> Source Name:
> ***_Transfer
> Objects Task  Source ID:
> {9135C978-DD50-4418-A843-7E8FCE455181}
> Execution ID:
> {F6819FBA-4258-4723-B87D-525F1CF0673B}
> Start Time: 19/08/2009 16:21:39  End
> Time: 19/08/2009 16:21:39  Data Code:
> 0
```

I'm getting this error in the event log after trying to copy a database on my server. All I'm trying to do is create a copy for a test site on the same box. It has worked fine for another, smaller database.

Where would I find a more detailed error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you copying the database? I normally take a backup of a database, then just do a restore (as a different name) from that backup.